# Downloading S3 Files with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm currently trying to understand the ins and outs of amazon's S3 webservices.  The task of today is to successfully download an uploaded image (called an `asset` in my app).  I've been loosely following the guidelines in [this tutorial](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx354Y6VTZ421PJ/Downloading-Objects-from-Amazon-S3-using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby) in an effort to perform a direct download from the amazon server but seem to be missing something as nothing is downloading.

I'm using a `get`method in my `assets_controller` as follows:

```
def get
    asset = current_user.assets.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if asset
        File.open('file.png', 'w') do |file|
            s3 = AWS::S3::Client.new
            reap = s3.get_object({bucket_name: ENV['BUCKET'], key: URI.encode(asset.uploaded_file.path)}, target: file)
        end

    else
        flash[:error]="Don't be cheeky!  Mind your own assets"
    end
    redirect_to assets_path
end
```

I am not presented with any errors here and my logs indicate that the correct keys are being used.  However, no file downloads.  There must be something I'm not understanding or including.

**A couple additional questions that might help**

1. I'm not entirely sure what File.open is doing here; what is it doing in relation to the downloaded file?
2. I've added a `redirect_to` command to avoid a `missing_template` would this prevent the download from being triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You look to be downloading the file from s3 just fine (into file.png) but you're not doing anything with it, so it will never make it as far as the user's browser. The call to `File.open` opens the file into which the downloaded data is going.

Rails provides a `send_file` method that does this (this counts as a render so you'll need to not call redirect in that case or you'll get a double render error).

Alternatively you can generate a signed link and redirect the user to that. This avoids having to download the file to your server at all. With v2 of the sdk I believe you need to use the slightly higher level resource interface for this:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
s3.bucket(ENV['BUCKET']).object(object_key).presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 3600)
```

Generates a download link for the object valid for one hour

Comment: Ah, thanks so much; I didn't realize I had to do a send_file.  I was actually hoping to do the signed link redirect trick so I have a couple questions:  What do you mean by a "higher level resource interface?"  Also, I gave the above `presigned_url` code a shot and got hit with a `undefined method `bucket' `  I also tried it with `bucket_name` (as I'm using `gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'`) and that was no good either.  Any thoughts?  Thanks again!

Comment: The resource interface is what you get with Aws::S3::Resource (rather than Aws::S3::Client), but this is a sdk v2 thing

Comment: Hi again, I'm attempting to get the send_file method right but I keep downloading a file that's 0 bytes in size.  My send_file line is as follows: `send_file 'file.png type: asset.uploaded_file_content_type`.  Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?